# id nil when select model without no relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with no relation.

```
class GridConfig < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

my question is why result of query are appended **id:nil** columns?

```
GridConfig.select(:fontSize)
```

result is

```
#<GridConfig id: nil, fontSize: "12px">
```

is there any options for this?

thank you.

---

I want find some records and pick certain columns. and send to client.

```
user_key = params[:user_key]
grid_id = params[:grid_id]

@config = GridConfig.where(['user_key = ? and grid_id = ?', user_key, grid_id])
    .select(:model_id, :fontSize, :displayCount, :columnModel)

# i checked @config variables at this point and found nil:id...

@config = @config.index_by(&:model_id)

# and i want to this makes indexed by model_id like [{"model":{...}},{"model2" : {...}}, {}]

respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @config }
end
```

Comment: Try using with `find`.

Comment: `select` is used to select only certain columns from the db, therefore it's the only column that is set to a value. What are you trying to achieve specifically?

Comment: If you only want the font size you can use the `pluck` method. GridConfig.pluck(:fontSize).first will return only '12px'.

Comment: i added contents for this questions. sorry for insufficient contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method to select only certain columns into an array, then index by the first column.

```
@config = GridConfig.where(user_key: params[:user_key], grid_id: params[:grid_id])
   .pluck(:model_id, :fontSize, :displayCount, :columnModel)

@config = @config.index_by{ |x| x[0] }
```